# Putting onClickListeners on dynamically added LinearLayouts

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am trying to add a clickListener to an ImageButton that's inside a dynamically added LinearLayout, which is part of another (wrapper) LinearLayout:

Wrapper:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/persons_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Dynammically added LinearLayout to the above wrapper:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/person_row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_with_person"
        android:src="@drawable/share_with"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="35dp"

        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person_name"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:hint="@string/person_name_hint"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_form_elements"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/person_amount"
        android:textColor="@color/secondary_text_color"
        android:hint="10.20"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_between_form_elements"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code for adding a clickListener to the ImageButton in the above Layout:

```
ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.persons_wrapper);

for (int i = 0; i < parentView.getChildCount(); i++) {
    //get the parent's childview, which is the linear layout wrapped around the name and amount for a person
    final View childView = parentView.getChildAt(i);
    Log.i("for loop", "looping");
    ImageButton shareWithPerson = (ImageButton) childView.findViewById(R.id.share_with_person);

    shareWithPerson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("clicked", "share");


            shareTextWithChosenApp(childView);
        }
    });
    shareWithPerson.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            Log.i("clicked", "long click");
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

There is no error or what so ever but after clicking the ImageButton simply nothing happens.

Things I've checked:

- "clicked", "looping" is logged
- `parentView` is not null  childView and
- `shareWithPerson` is not null and are the desired Views

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:

The shareTextWithChosenApp method:

```
 private void shareTextWithChosenApp(View personRow) {
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

        TextView personAmount = (TextView) personRow.findViewById(R.id.person_amount);
        String shareBody = personAmount.getText().toString();

        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Rekening delen");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Delen met: "));

    }
```

Comment: Well, if you onClicklistener is called, as your logging indicates, then the problem appears to be in your shareTextWithChosenApp Method, which you did not provide.

Comment: I will add that method, but I think you're wrong because the log should appear even before the shareTextWithChosenApp is called.

Comment: didnt you say, that "clicked" is logged?, and by logged i mean printed to logcat

Comment: Well, that's my bad, I did not change the tag after copying it from inside the onClick. It should be something like: "for loop", "inside"

Comment: ah ok, so your problem is that you dont register your click events. This appears to be some sort of homemade listview. why would you try to build your own?

Comment: I managed to solved the problem. In the onResume() I refilled the persons list and therefore the listeners are overwritten and not set again.

Comment: you should use a listview, and implement a proper getView method, so you dont have to take care of setting the listener yourself.